# jquery ajax data does not replace variable to values on request

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am using jquery 3.3.1 and codeigniter.I have this code below which is an ajax request with csrf tokens and some data.

```
var csrfHash = "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>";
var csrfName = "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>";
function save(sid){
    var newname = $('#s'+sid).val();    
    $.ajax({
        url:'<?php echo base_url();?>schoolmaster/School/update',
        data:{csrfName:csrfHash,'id':sid,'schoolname':newname},
        type:'POST',
        success:function(response){
            var response_json = JSON.parse(response);
            if(response_json['message'] == 'TRUE'){
                alert("Success");                    
            }else{
                alert("Failed to update.");                    
            }
            csrfName = response_json['csrfName'];
            csrfHash = response_json['csrfHash'];              
        }
    });       
}
```

[check image for form data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLLBl.png)

If you see the image the 'id' and 'schoolname' have been passsed correctly but csrfName contains the actual name of the csrf variable.But it did not change to  'csrf_test_name'. It should be something like

```
data:{'csrf_test_name':csrfHash,'id':sid,'schoolname':newname}
```

this works fine,but I want it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do it direct in `$.ajax`

You'd rather build your `Json Object` like this:

```
var csrfHash = "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>";
var csrfName = "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>";

var MyJson:{id:sid, schoolname:newname}; // <- not using [''] for keys
MyJson[csrfName]:csrfHash;
```

And then

```
 $.ajax({
    url:'<?php echo base_url();?>schoolmaster/School/update',
    data: MyJson,
    type:'POST',
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks .this did the job perfectly